# Trying to figure out how to use UPDATE in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just learning SQL so I still have a long way to go to figure everything out. I'm trying to write an UPDATE in a `customer` table that shows any customer 30 days delinquent on their account and will make them inactive.

My table consists of: `Customerid`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Startdate`, `Billingcycle`, `Phone`, `Streetaddress`, `City`, `State`, `Zip`, `Employeeid`, `Status`, `Reason`, `Statusdate`, and `Email`.

I tried the following, but no luck;

```
UPDATE customer
SET status = (
SELECT status
FROM customer
WHERE status = billingcycle + 30)
WHERE status = 'INACTIVE';
```

Any help here?

Comment: What is the datatype of `Statusdate`?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE customer
SET status = 'INACTIVE'
WHERE billingcycle < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the BillingDate as the basis for checking deliquency:

```
UPDATE customer
SET status = 'INACTIVE'
WHERE (trunc(sysdate)-BilingDate) = 30
```

And if it is 30 days an above you just change = to >= like:

```
UPDATE customer
SET status = 'INACTIVE'
WHERE (trunc(sysdate)-BilingDate) >=30
```

Or inferring from your post the column is `BillingCycle` then you can change `BillingDate` to `BillingCycle` like:

```
UPDATE customer
SET status = 'INACTIVE'
WHERE (trunc(sysdate)-Bilingcycle) >=30
```

Comment: Good and well explained answer. I'd recommend to solve for the table column and put the constants on the other side of the condition so that an index could be used (if there is one): `billingcycle <= trunc(sysdate) - 30`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update customer 
set status = 'INACTIVE' 
 where getdate() > dateadd(dd, 30, billingcycle);`
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how this is expressed in Oracle because my background is in SQL Server. The getdate() could be replaced with a cutoff date parameter.  Billing cycle will need to be a date column, and you will need to add 30 days to that date using something like a dateadd function. At any rate, if the left hand side is less than the last billing cycle + 30 days, then they're overdue.